# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '-f'

Tags: python, kernel, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

While running Jupyter notebook, the following error occurs:
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '-f'
Changing kernel.json and setting the python.exe path did not work:

```
{
 "display_name": "Python 2", 
 "language": "python", 
 "argv": [
 "C:\\Users\\XYZ\\Anaconda2\\python.exe",
  "-m", 
  "ipykernel_launcher", 
  "-f", 
  "{connection_file}"
 ]
}
```

Suggestions are really appreciated!

Comment: I assume Python exists in the specified directory but does the connection_file also exist?

Comment: Am I supposed to manually create it?